# lightning-input should accept numbers only in lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components

lightning-input type="text" value={intNum} label="Enter Value" onchange={onChange} pattern="[0-9]+" title="numbers only">

this is not working somebody please help

Comment: I suggest to spend some time going through `lightning-input` documentation. This is very entry level question and clearly shows that you haven't really went through documentation or any training related to LWC. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/documentation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `lightning-input type="number"`, also

> If you don't specify step, the default value of 1 allows users to enter only integers.

so you will have only Integers as you wanted (assumed from your pattern).

[Link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-input/documentation) to SF documentation.

Comment: Thank you for your reply

Comment: lightning-input type="number" , it allows some letters like k,b is there any method to restrict it

Comment: Number Shortcuts such as k, K, m, M, b, B, t, and T are allowed. For the en-US locale, when you enter 1k the field displays 1,000. Entering 1m results in 1,000,000. When the input field is focused, the input value is the multiplied number. For example, entering 1k results in 1,000 on blur, and 1000 when the input is focused again. @MarthalaLokesh So the answer is: you cannot restrict number shortcuts, but they will turn into normal values after clicking somewhere else outside the input area.